# remove items at multiple indexes in an array

Tags: swift

code below removes only the first item in the array with color property set to "black"

```
struct car {
    let model: String
    let color: String
}

var myCars :[car] = [
    car(name:"model X", color: "black"),
    car(name:"model Y", color: "blue"),
    car(name:"roadster", color: "red"),
    car(name:"model S", color: "black"),
    car(name:"model 3", color: "black")
]

let delList = myCars.index(where: {$0.color == "black"})
myCars.remove(at: delList)
```

i want delete all the items in the array with the color property set to "black"

Comment: Also - please don't just ask questions if you haven't done any research prior. You are definitely not the first asking this.

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
print("Before: \(myCars)")
myCars.removeAll(where: {$0.color == "black"})
print("After: \(myCars)")
```